# Why is my Task Suspended? Swift, dataTaskWithURL

Tags: swift

I have the following swift code

```
let urlPath="..." // dont worry, there is an actual valid URL in there
let url=NSURL(strong: urlPath)
let session=NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task=session.dataTaskWithURL(url!,completionHandler:{data,response,error -> Void in
    println("Task Completed")
})

println(task)
```

When I run this code, the console never shows the line `"Task Completed"`, instead it shows the following:

```
<__NSCFLocalDataTask: 0x7c923180>{ taskIdentifier: 1 } { suspended }
```

Why is my task suspended, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need to start the execution of your task using

```
task.resume()
```

Comment: As we mostly ignore the very little little things which really counts. Thanks for reminding those little things. :)